# How to keep delay after each submit happening inside a For loop?

Tags: javascript

I want to keep 10 seconds delay after each submit

This is my sample program

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function sleep(ms)
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
        while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
    }

function test() {
var windowCounter = 1; 
var myStringArray = [ "user1", "user2" , "user3" , "user4" ]
var len = myStringArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
   document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time
    document.inform.submit();
}
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body >
  <form name="inform"   target="newWin" action="https://www.google.co.in/">
 <input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="test()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried these options till now

```
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {

if(i==1)
sleep(10000);
if(i==2)
sleep(10000);

   document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time
    document.inform.submit();
}
```

But still all submits  are being called at same time

Then

```
var windowCounter = 1;
for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.inform.target = windowCounter++; 
        document.inform.cid.value="XXXX";
        document.inform.pw.value="xxxxx";
        document.inform.submit();
    }, i*10000); // 
}
```

But when i added this timeout i was getting some cr-ns-error-not-available ( Due to the Timeout)

FInally i tried , but still are being called at same time

```
 var len = 1;
    var len2 = 1;
    var len3 = 1;

    if(len==1)
    {
    sleep(4000);
       document.inform.target = 1; // a different target each time
        document.inform.submit();
    }


    if(len2==1)
    {
    sleep(4000);
       document.inform.target = 2; // a different target each time
        document.inform.submit();
    }
```

Is there any solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a function like this and call it :-

```
  var i = 1;                     
   function A() {           
  setTimeout(function () {    
  i++;                    
  if (i < 10) {            
     A();            
  }                        
  }, 3000)
}

 A();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand that much of your question but this maybe/can be usefull:
If each form has test() as an inline onclick function then this should probably work somehow.

```
var windowCounter = 0;
function test() { 
   windowCounter++;
   setTimeout(function(){
     if(windowCounter == 1) // bla
     else if(windowCounter == 2) // bla
  }, 10000);
}
```